# Cambiar la posición de un elemento en una lista, y mantenerla ordenada

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos, algoritmos

Tengo una lista de elementos cuyos indices son números no consecutivos, y están agrupados por ejemplo

```
1, a, uno
3, a, dos
4, a, tres
5, a, cuatro
9, a, cinco
2, b, seis
6, b, siete
7, b, ocho
8, b, nueve
10,b, diez
```

esta lista tiene dos grupos a y b los elementos solo solo pueden cambiar de posición dentro de su propio grupo, y al cambiar de lugar tienen que recorrerse el resto de elementos para que el orden se preserve por ejemplo

```
1, a, uno
3, a, cinco
4, a, dos
5, a, tres
9, a, cuatro
2, b, seis
6, b, siete
7, b, ocho
8, b, nueve
10,b, diez
```

Hay representación de esta esta lista, en base de datos, en json y html, 
si la lista es consecutiva, no tengo problema

Comment: ¿y el problema exacto es?

Comment: Ya no se como abordar el problema, ya que si la lista es consecutiva solo hace un espacio (se suma 1) en destino el resto se recorre toda la lista, pero al no ser consecutivo el el espacio entre elementos ya no es 1, el orden se pierde y en repinen indices

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, cuando cambias de posición un elemento re indexas toda lista, para preservar el orden que en pseudocódigo seria algo así.

```
Si destino es tope entonces // En el caso que movamos un elemento al principio de la lista
 contador = 2
 Desde inicio lista hasta fin de lista hacer elemento
  Si indice elemento != indice origen
   indice de elemento = contador
   contador + 1
  Fin si
 Fin hacer
indice destino = 1
Si no 
 contador1 = 1
 contador2 = indice destino + 2
 Desde inicio lista hasta fin de lista hacer elemento
  Si indice elemento != indice origen y indice elemento <= indice destino
   indice de elemento = contador1
   contador1 + 1
  Fin si
  Si indice elemento != indice origen y indice elemento > indice destino
   indice de elemento = contador2
   contador2 + 1
  Fin si
 Fin hacer
 indice origen = indice destino + 1
Fin si
```

Básicamente toma la lista ordenada y genera nuevos indices manteniendo el orden de

```
1, a, uno
3, a, dos
4, a, tres
5, a, cuatro
9, a, cinco
2, b, seis
6, b, siete
7, b, ocho
8, b, nueve
10,b, diez
```

a

```
1, a, uno
2, a, cinco
3, a, dos
4, a, tres
5, a, cuatro
6, b, seis
7, b, siete
8, b, ocho
9, b, nueve
10,b, diez
```